# Use "Go to symbol" and "Go to symbol in workspace" in VS Code for Ruby

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, language-server-protocol

Is it possible to use the "Go to symbol" and "Go to symbol in workspace" features in VS Code for Ruby files? These work great, out of the box, for JavaScript, but they seem to be non-existent for Ruby.

For instance, it seems like the most popular Ruby extensions, [Ruby](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rebornix.Ruby), and [Ruby Solargraph](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=castwide.solargraph), don't support this feature. [Ruby Symbols](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=miguel-savignano.ruby-symbols) supports symbols, but only in the current file, not the entire workspace.

Comment: [This](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jaydenlin.ctags-support) might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solargraph received quite a few updates since Mar 2018 and it supports [workspace symbols](https://solargraph.org/guides/language-server#supported-capabilities) for some time already.